# Moving character left and right

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hello i followed a tutorial on how to make a top down shooter, the code makes so that my character rotates against my mouse and i can move forward and backwards using W and S. However i also want to be able to move right and left using A and D im not good when it comes to code in javascript nor unity3d i do most of my coding in c#. And the guy that made the tutorial explained poorly what some of the code actually do.

Here is the code:

```
#pragma strict

var speed : float = 20.0;
var rotateSpeed : float = 2.0;

function Update () {

var controller : CharacterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
transform.Rotate(0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed,0);

var forward : Vector3 = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
var curSpeed : float = speed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
controller.SimpleMove(forward * curSpeed);

var position = Input.mousePosition;
var newposition = Vector3(position.x,position.y,camera.main.transform.position.y- transform.position.y);
var lastposition = camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(newposition);
transform.LookAt(lastposition);

}

@script RequireComponent(CharacterController)
```

Comment: Are you asking us to convert this UnityScript to C#? What have you tried for yourself? On Stackoverflow, some research and own attempts are requested.

Answer (score 1):

code for staffing (moving left and right without turning)

```
if(Input.GetKeyUp("d")){ 
    controller.SimpleMove(right * staffingSpeed);
}
else if(Input.GetKeyUp("a")) {
    controller.SimpleMove(-right * staffingSpeed);
}
```

write the code in update() function and make a variable "staffingSpeed" outside the function and set it from inspector 
or 
replace "staffingSpeed" with a constant numeric value e.g 5